# ERROR: jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named python3 occurs in Airflow/papermill running as a docker container

Tags: kernel, airflow, jupyter, papermill

I am trying to run an example papermill notebook that you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/airflow/providers/papermill/example_dags): at the Official Apache Airflow url

[airflow-github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7s64.png)

with a corresponding dag file, found within the same directory as specified above.

I am running this locally using a docker-compose assembly that you can find [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) at the Airflow website:

[airflow-docker-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikdA0.png)

I had to custom build the image with Papermill because it looks like it is not baked into the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1scTI.png)

Here is an error I am getting:

```
raise NoSuchKernel(kernel_name)
```

jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named python3

How do I add the kernel?

UPDATE:
I managed to resolve this issue but now have this:

[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {execute.py:84} INFO - Input Notebook:  /opt/***/dags/example_notebook.ipynb
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {execute.py:85} INFO - Output Notebook: out-2021-10-28T22:47:55.826195+00:00.ipynb
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:192} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:195} INFO - Writing grammar tables to /home/***/.cache/black/21.9b0/Grammar3.6.15.final.0.pickle
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:199} INFO - Writing failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/airflow/.cache/black/21.9b0/tmp27kcm8y_'
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:192} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:195} INFO - Writing grammar tables to /home/***/.cache/black/21.9b0/PatternGrammar3.6.15.final.0.pickle
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {driver.py:199} INFO - Writing failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/airflow/.cache/black/21.9b0/tmpnexc_sob'
[2021-10-28, 22:47:57 UTC] {warnings.py:99} WARNING - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:67: UserWarning: IPython parent '/home/***' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
" using a temp directory.".format(parent))

Answer (score 14):

I got same issue with you,

I resovled it by add there rows in Docker file

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip ipython ipykernel
RUN ipython kernel install --name "python3" --user
```

And then

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Here is my full Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.1   
COPY requirement.txt .   
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip ipython ipykernel   
RUN ipython kernel install --name "python3" --user
CMD python -m ipykernel_launcher -f $DOCKERNEL_CONNECTION_FILE
```

Comment: really appreciated

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip ipython ipykerne   was enough for me to solve the error. thank you.